# summing up rows of two or more vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sum, row

If I have two vectors say:

```
element_collect(:,:,1) =

1.3689
2.7376
3.4220
3.7642
3.9353

element_collect(:,:,2) =

1.3688
2.0531
2.3953
3.7640
5.7316
```

Now, I want to add rows of both vectors one by one to get new results.

e.g: if I add 1st rows of both vectors, i should get the result something like this:

```
z(:,:,1) = 1.3689 + 1.3688 (=2.7377)
```

Similarly, if I add 2nd rows of both vectors, i should get the result as:

```
z(:,:,2) = 2.7376 + 2.0531 (=4.7907)
```

and similarly for all other rows.

- I tried using the following code but I dont get the desired results:

  z = sum(element_collect)

Can someone help me getting the results that I want!

Thanks

Comment: Remember those are not rows, they are elements in the third dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this for your example -

```
z = sum(element_collect(:,:,1:2),3)
```

If you would like to add up 3, 4 and 5 too in the third dimension, simply do -

```
z = sum(element_collect(:,:,1:5),3)
```

If you would like to add up all those in the third dimension, do this -

```
z = sum(element_collect(:,:,:),3)
```